# Retriving Public folder's additional properties

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

> Is there a way where we can fetch public folders additional properties
>   like - list of users and their current rights.

I have tried to list all public folders like this-

```
    <soap:Body>
    <FindFolder Traversal="Shallow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
    <FolderShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
    </FolderShape>
    <ParentFolderIds>
            <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="publicfoldersroot"/>
    </ParentFolderIds>
    </FindFolder>
</soap:Body>
```

Now how can I make another soap request to list properties of a particular public folder?

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving folder properties, you need to request `folder:PermissionSet` property:

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-set-folder-permissions-for-another-user-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: I was able to create public folder but the mail enables option was 'diable' by default for the newly created public folder. How can I change that?

Comment: You can change the permissions after you create the folder.